# getting indexOutOfRange Exception

Tags: c#, exception, datagridview

getting an exception with the message "There is no row at position 1".

if we enter 2 rows or more in the datatgridview, and clik the save button it inserts only then first row and the gives an exception.

here is the snippet:

```
private void btnSave_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
   for (int i = 0; i < dataGridView1.Rows.Count; i++)
   {
         table = obj.select("select id from stock where item_name='" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[0].FormattedValue + "'");
          obj.query("insert into poi_items (po_id, stock_id, description, expected_price, discount, quantity, expected_total, status, received)values(" + textBox3.Text + "," + table.Rows[i][0] + ",'" + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[1].FormattedValue + "'," + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[3].FormattedValue + "," + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[5].FormattedValue + "," + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[2].FormattedValue + "," + dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].FormattedValue + ",'Open','0')");                    
   }

 }
```

Comment: if you debug and put a breakpoint in your for loop, what does dataGridView1.Rows look like?

Comment: when it comes to the second row of datagridview and executes the second query it gives me the exception at dataGridView1.Rows[i].Cells[6].FormattedValue

Comment: Does Rows have two entries at the point in the debugger?

Answer (score 1):

it seems that in your query

```
table.Rows[i]
```

is what is throwing the exception. Make sure that you have 2 rows in your table.

Comment: Just out of interest, wouldn't the Count ensure there were 2 rows in this case? Or is there some threading issue going on here were Count is updated while Rows[1] is still null?

Comment: @Richard count is placed on gridviewrows, not on table rows.